# Which library file to be added to software repository after adding a library via composer?

Tags: composer-php

I just started to use composer and the first library I added was predis-1.0. Installation was successful but I found myself not quite following the official document.

Documentation said:

```
To use it, just add the following line to your code's bootstrap process: require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

But I copied vendor directory into my repository and add require 'vendor/autoload.php'. What I got was a PHP error:

```
Class 'Predis\Client' not found.
```

Then I removed vendor directory from repository and copied autoload.php and src directory from predis-1.0 to repository. This time everything works fine.

So I just wonder
1. Is this the way composer supposed to be working?
2. Should I add predis-1.0's autoload.php and src directory into my software repository? And are these enough?

Thanks in advance.

PS: predis-1.0 structure:

```
 2015-03-21  21:18    <DIR>          .
 2015-03-21  21:18    <DIR>          ..
 2015-01-02  20:54               312 autoload.php
 2015-03-21  09:43    <DIR>          bin
 2015-01-02  20:54            39,331 CHANGELOG.md
 2015-01-02  20:54               882 composer.json
 2015-03-21  10:50            33,695 composer.lock
 2015-01-02  20:54             2,649 CONTRIBUTING.md
 2015-03-21  21:18    <DIR>          examples
 2015-01-02  20:54             8,537 FAQ.md
 2015-01-02  20:54             1,067 LICENSE
 2015-01-02  20:54               903 package.ini
 2015-01-02  20:54            17,787 README.md
 2015-03-21  09:43    <DIR>          src
 2015-03-21  21:09    <DIR>          vendor
 2015-01-02  20:54                10 VERSION
```

Comment: Can you show us the location and content of **your own** `composer.json` file and the location of your test script. And why were you copying the vendor directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't move things around. It will just get you in trouble.

Composer fetches the dependencies into the defined vendor-dir. End of story.

--

In your project you have a composer.json.
This file requires predis 1.0.

In your application bootstrap you simple include `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`.
That means, that you load the Composer autoloader, which includes all the dependencies, including predis.

Run `composer install` - dependencies are fetched, autoloading created.

Then run your application. Done.